# Passing serialized data from PHP to JavaScript in array

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, woocommerce

I am trying to pass WooCommerce product information from PHP to Javascript using AJAX so it can be updated on the front end as certain values change.  I have got most of the process working fine but I am having some issues sending a serialized piece of data to JavaScript and receiving it correctly.

PHP

```
add_action('wp_ajax_variation_action', 'get_variation_details');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_variation_action', 'get_variation_details');

function get_variation_details(){
    $variation_id = $_POST['variation'];
    $product = wc_get_product($variation_id);
    $sku = $product->get_sku();
    $description = $product->get_description();
    $downloads = $product->get_downloads();
    $downloads = unserialize($downloads);

    $variation_info[] = array(
        'sku' => $sku,
        'description' => $description,
        'downloads' => $downloads,
    );

    echo json_encode($variation_info);
    exit;
}
```

Here I am getting some values such as the product SKU and description before putting them in an array called $variation_info and JSON encoding this array before echoing it back to the JS.

This works fine but the problem arises with the $downloads variable.  The data being pulled in here is stored as a serialized string and when I pass this across to the JS it is only passing the very first part of the string.  I have tried to use the unserialize function here first but that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: What is the value of `unserialize($downloads);`? Does it contain any data structures that JSON does not support?

Comment: It's not giving back anything as I'm getting the message 'unserialize() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given'. So it's not a serialized string.. A serialized array?

Comment: You should focus on that rather then on sending stuff back to JS. Figure out what stuff you have first.

Comment: "So it's not a serialized string.. A serialized array?" — A serialized array … would be a string. If the error says it is an array, then it is an array.